# Ionic - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token On APK

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile

I have an error since yesterday I try to fix. I successfully built an android apk using:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

But the app stuck on white screen on device and emulator (GenyMotion). I inspected the logcat of GenyMotion. I figured out these:

```
>  I/chromium( 5497): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", source: http://localhost/runtime.fcad956485f9614ff8b1.js (1)
>  D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5497): http://localhost/polyfills.49d987a1d15d60566c3f.js: Line 1 : Uncaught  SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
> I/chromium( 5497): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>", source: http://localhost/polyfills.49d987a1d15d60566c3f.js (1)
> D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5497): http://localhost/main.2be168d95557cbdc0a3f.js: Line 1 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

> I/chromium( 5497): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>", source: http://localhost/main.2be168d95557cbdc0a3f.js (1)
```

I don't know why. They are no errors when building.

My package.json

```
... 
"@angular/common": "~12.0.1",
"@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
"ionic": "^5.4.16",
"cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
... 
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
"typescript": "~4.2.4"
```

My tsconfig.json.

```
...  
"target": "es2015", 
"module": "es2020",
"lib": ["es2018", "dom"] 
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a real battle in order to fix the issue since 3 days,
i solved the problem.
Ionic 5 angular 12 use es2015 as a target when building.
I set "target" to es5 in tsconfig.json and errors in runtime.**.js, polyfills.**.json disappeared

es5 transform ES6 function to standard functions.

More info at
[https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)

Answer (score 1):

ionic + angular has update the type script compiler in the recent update as
`Root folder > tcconfig.json > compilerOptions > target > es2020` - This is causing the issue in android version 29

Chang the target as `es2015` to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty clear. You have a syntax error. I suppose you can check logs for `ionic cordova build android --prod`. Probably It will show which files and lines generate these problems.

If you use linter you can try to run `npm run lint` to check any problems with your code.

Comment: Hello Danil. Thanks for answer. I run   **npm run lint** . No serious error shown. All are about best practices such camelCase, Strict comparison, declare const.   No error related to )   =>  found.   Also, i migrated to cordova-android@latest. I still have the error

Comment: @Rehum In this case, you can try check logs in Chrome developer tools (with `ionic serve`) or check your launch logic for syntax errors. Your code definitely has syntax errors. Usually, a lot of brackets places near with `Observable.subscribe` and `Promise.then().catch()` logic.

Comment: Waouhh. It's a lot of code.  I run 1stly  **ionic cordova build browser --prod** . It helps me to fix some parts of the code.  When i run **ionic serve**  No error happens.    When i inspect devices with chrome  **chrome://inspects#devices** . It mentions the same errors mentionned above.  I send the code on online JS lint platform. No serious errors found. Really. i don't know

Comment: @rehum how did you solve the issue, i have the exact same issue,

Comment: Hello @BonifacePereira, i solved it after a real battle. Just see the accepted answer